# Show that the ideal generated by an inner function is closed.

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-algebras, hardy-spaces

Suppose $H^\infty=\{f\in H(U):\exists M<\infty,\,\forall z\in U,\,|f(z)|\le M\}$ is the set of bounded holomorphic functions in the unit disk. It is a Banach algebra with pointwise multiplication.

Let $\varphi$ is an [inner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Factorization_into_inner_and_outer_functions_.28Beurling.29), $f_n\in H^\infty$, $n=1,2,\ldots$, and $\varphi\cdot f_n\rightrightarrows g$. I am asked to show that $g/\varphi\in H^\infty$.

I tried Beurling factorization but did not succeed. The result is not true if $\varphi$ is not required to be an inner function. For example, $\varphi_0(z)=(z-1)^2$, the ideal generated by $\varphi_0$ is not closed.

Can anyone give a proof (or a hint)?

Comment: Show that if $z$ is a zero of $\phi$ of order $n$, then it must be a zero of $g$ of at least order $n$. Then $\phi / g$ will be an honest to goodness bounded analytic function. The innerness of $\phi$ allows you to say it is bounded, I believe.

Comment: What does the double-arrow convergence mean here?

Comment: @TrialAndError It means convergence in supremum norm, and also means uniform convergence, since they are the same.

Comment: @EclipseSun : Then, it would follow that $f_{n}\rightarrow \overline{\varphi}g$ in the essential sup norm on $\mathbb{T}$, and this boundary function is the boundary function of $f \in H^{\infty}$. So $f\varphi =g$ is in $H^{\infty}$.

Comment: @Disintegrating by Parts, why did you say “this (boundary) function is the boundary function of $f \in H^\infty$? What result did you apply?

Comment: @KKWong $f_n \in H^{\infty}$ converges in the essential sup norm to $f$. So $f\in H^{\infty}$.